Issue with HtmlService placement in HTML file - Web app GAS
I am trying to Build a chart in Web App - GAS. I have Dropdown
Dropdown List values are - All, North, South. By default when page loads I need to render the chart with "All" Values. On selection of dropdown and button click, the chart has to filtered.
I am getting the error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')" With this error I could not move forward, I got stuck here.
Is this because of getRange in my GAS script, which is an 2D array. Help me out with the solutions.
My Sample data from Google Sheets looks like

Update of my Question:
As Cooper advised I removed this Tag
<?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('p_style').getContent();?>

Chart is rendering but CSS are not referencing, when I include this CSS are fine but I am getting the error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')"
Here is what I am trying
My GAS Code:
function doGet(e){
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('pages');           

  var dg = get_dg();
  html.dg=dg;  
  return html.evaluate();       
}

function doPost(e){  

  var dg = e.parameters.dg.toString();
  

  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('pages');             
  var dg = get_dg();  
  html.dg=dg;  
  return html.evaluate();
}

function getUrl() {
 var url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl(); 
 return url;
}

function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
      .getContent();
}

function get_dg(){
  var d_useremail = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('XXXXXXXXX');
  var metrics_sheet = ss.getSheetByName('sheet');
  var getlastrow = metrics_sheet.getLastRow();  
  var return_array=[];  
  for(var i = 2; i <= getlastrow; i++)
  {
      if(metrics_sheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue() === d_useremail) {                
        return_array.push(metrics_sheet.getRange(i, 2).getValue());
      }
  }
  Logger.log(return_array);
  return return_array.filter(uniquelists);
}

function draw_linechart(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
  var metrics_sheet = ss.getSheetByName('test_chart');

  var c_data= metrics_sheet.getRange("A1:B").getValues();
  var c_data1 = JSON.stringify(c_data);   
  return c_data1;
}

page_style CSS Code
.c_line_chart{
  display:flex;
  width:90%;
  height:90px;
  margin-left:35px;    
}

pages My HTML Code
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>  
  <head>
    <base target="_top">    
     
    <?!= include('page_style'); ?>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">   
    
      google.charts.load('current',{'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawchart);

      function drawchart(){
        window.alert('Inside Draw Chart func');
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(displaychart).draw_linechart();
      }

      function displaychart(c_data1){

        var chartdata =  new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(JSON.parse(c_data1));
        console.log(chartdata);        

      //Setting Chart Options

      var options={
        title: 'Checking the Charts',
        is3D: true
      }

      // Draw our chart passing some options
      var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('line_chart'));
      chart.draw(chartdata,options);
      }
      </script>
  </head>
<body>
<?var url =getUrl(); ?>    
<form method="post" action="<?= url ?>" >
<div class="filter_container">
      <br><br>
      <div class="box1">      
        <label class="label_"> DGraph </label> <br>
        <select name="s_d" id="dg" class="cselect">
        <option style="color:#D3D3D3" value="All"  selected disabled hidden > Choose </option>
        <? for(var i=0; i< dg.length;i++){ ?>
        <option value="<?= dg[i] ?>" ><?= dg[i] ?></option>
        <? } ?>
        </select><br><br>
      </div>
<button id ="btn" type="button">Click!</button>
</div>
<div id ="line_chart" class="c_line_chart"><div>
</form>
</body>
</html>


dg is apparently undefined.  HtmlService is a server side function and should not be in your html.   Also if you are using snippets then you are creating a template that needs to be evaluated before it becomes html

Thanks Cooper!! I tried removing HTMLService chart is showing up but my CSS are not referencing to HTML page. Tried "Include" as well no luck still the same error. Would you help me in referencing the CSS to HTML in a correct way. Thanks!

Try putting into the head tag. Does it have it's own style tags?

Tried putting in the Head tag, still the same error. p_style is my css file

The p_style file is missing. Also, the get getUrl() function and the dg variable declarations are missing. Please add a [mcve].

Wicket - Edited.

Thanks for letting me know. The question still needs critical details like the web app deployment settings, which will be executed as the user accesses the web app, if this will be done with any account or only with Google Workspace accounts.

@Tpk43 About your message of Hi Tanaike, I have a similar problem here stackoverflow.com/questions/78941716/… pls let me know what is wrong here. Thanks!!, when I saw your posted question, I confirmed that an answer has already been posted. In this case, I would like to respect the existing answer.

From the question

I am getting the error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')" With this error I could not move forward, I got stuck here.

The question only includes one statement having length:
<? for(var i=0; i< dg.length;i++){ ?>

Considering this, the problem is that dg is undefined. The relevant function is doGet. The declaration of dg on this function is
var dg = get_dg();

So, the problem is that get_dg() returning undefined. The return statement of this function is
return return_array.filter(uniquelists);

It's noteworthy that uniquelists is not declared in the question. Despite this, apparently, the expression return_array.filter(uniquelists) is returning undefined.
I suggest you,

Clean up your "minimal complete example," i.e., the doPost function doesn't look to be required.
Create a test function for the  get_dg() function, so you can verify that it is working correctly. Example:
function test_get_dg(){
  const result = get_dg();
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(result);
}


As the function uses Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(), you should share your project with a test account because this expression sometimes returns null. This behavior might require you to change your script profoundly.


It was  I am messing up with. Thank you very much for helping me out. Now I able to draw the charts. I am trying to filter charts on Drop down selection. Will let you know In case I am stuck again. Thanks again.
